# RegEx to match only a newline character with given conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

I have the following RegEx:

```
^(?!#)(?<=.+)$\r
```

*(with the global and multiline flags set)*

What I *want* to do is match a newline **only** when it ends a line that doesn't start with '#'.

Comment: So don't you want the dollar *after* the `\r`?

Comment: @ELR: Just to be sure, I removed the `$`, but it still doesn't work. The `\r` probably shouldn't even be there when using multiline and `$`.

Comment: And Javascript regex doesn't support lookbehind :(

Comment: Yes I think in multiline mode the `$` matches newline however it's zero-length. Are you wanting to replace newlines?

Comment: @ELR: Yes. That's right... but with the above conditions.

Comment: I'd be tempted to `.split` on newline, iterate through the array and add a newline to anything not starting with `#` and then `.join`.

Comment: @ElR: Hmmm... that does sound easier. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: That's a smart one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doSplit(input){
   var newl=String.fromCharCode(13)+String.fromCharCode(10); //make a newline
   var str = sInput.value.split(/\n/);                       //split on newlines
    for (var i=0,iMax=str.length; i<iMax; i++){              //loop through  
         //if it starts # add a newline
        if (str[i][0]=='#') {str[i]+=newl;}                 
    };

   return str.join('');   //join it back up
}
```

[Example here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kVf2V/)

Of course this will actually add a non-existent newline at the end (if the final line starts with #) so change the loop to avoid this eg...

```
for (var i=0,iMax=str.length-1; i<iMax; i++){              //loop through
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see a comparison of execution times of this function against a regex solution...

Answer (score 0):

The zero-width look-ahead assertion takes care about the "doesn't start with", but I think you're mixing up the uses of ^ and $ (in multiline-mode that is)

You probably want something like

```
(^|\n)(?!#)(\n)
```